# Modelviewer not loading local file "Not allowed to load local resource"

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, model-viewer

I'm using Google's [ModelViewer](https://modelviewer.dev/) for a WebAR project.

I have a vue.js project and I have a component that is loading the model with the `<model-viewer>` attribute. I'm trying to set the `src` attribute of the model-viewer to the **absolute path** of the *.glb* model in my project folder. (Note: I have to use the absolute path, otherwise it will not load nor display any error).

This is the html code in the vue component:

```html
<model-viewer
  src="*path-to-project*/src/assets/models/Astronaut.glb"
  alt="A 3D model of an astronaut"
  ar
  ar-modes="webxr scene-viewer quick-look"
  ar-placement="floor"
  environment-image="neutral"
  auto-rotate
  camera-controls
></model-viewer>
```

The model is not loaded in the web page and the console shows the following error:

> Not allowed to load local resource: file:///path-to-project/src/assets/models/Astronaut.glb

Loading from the URL provided in the official web's example works fine. I'm sure it's possible to load a local file and display it in ModelViewer, right?.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@/assets/models/Astronaut.glb` if you have it inside `src` folder

But for static assets, better to put it inside `public` folder like `public/models/Astronaut.glb`, and then in your component call it just `/models/Astronaut.glb`

Comment: thanks a lot!!! That worked! To clarify: the `@/assets/models/Astronaut.glb` didn't work, but the public folder and the `/models/Astronaut.glb` alternative, did.